# Waiting for an async function(Http request) before a form loads

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am writing a winform application and I would like to send a Http Post request and get a response *before* the main form loads. So far I am having the following situation:

If I do this, the form load will send the request, and the form will load immediately. The request response will arrive later but in the meantime any buttons in the form can be clicked (not the ideal )

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //client is a HttpClient
    //byteContent is a ByteArrayContent
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("theUrl", 
      byteContent))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Trace.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }

}
```

So I changed the code to this, and I thought the form would load after the request response arrives. However instead of this, what is happening is: The form appears before the response arrives but the mouse shows a loading revolving shape, therefore any buttons in the form is unavailable. Once the response arrives the buttons in the form becomes available.

This is correct but does not look that good.

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //client is a HttpClient
    //byteContent is a ByteArrayContent
    var PostTask = client.PostAsync("theUrl", byteContent);
    PostTask.Wait(); //blocking here

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = PostTask.Result)
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       Trace.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }

}
```

What would be the correct way to do what I want:

That the form shows *only* after the response arrives succesfully?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said whether you;re using WinForms or WPF.

If WinForms then one possibility would be to introduce a "Loading" form.  It would simply have the text:

```
"Please wait..."
```

or something.  You can then force a navigation to your main form once the call has finished.  This has the added advantage of giving you the option to handle the situation where your call doesn't complete.

If you're using WPF then you could bind the visibility of the controls to a `completed` or `loaded` flag (and the inverse to the visibility of a `Loading - please wait...` progress indicator).  You should also be able to handle this inside the View Model; meaning that you shouldn't need to have your code inside a form event.

I would also avoid using `.Wait()` to await your task.  A better method may be to use something like the [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I am using winform (edited the question now). But info on WPF is highly appreciated

Comment: Also thanks for the advice on wait. I'll take a look and get back to it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `Wait()` and `Result` in an `async` method?
Have you seen any compiler warnings?

Try this:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.Enable = false;

        //client is a HttpClient
        //byteContent is a ByteArrayContent

        using (var response = await client.PostAsync("theUrl", byteContent))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Trace.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Enable = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually no compiler warnings at all. By the way, isn't that the code that I posted and tried already?   I am calling Wait because I want the form loads *after* the response come. With the code above the form loads without waiting for the response.

Comment: No compiler warnings at all? No CS1998?

Comment: What happens if it takes too long?

Comment: Although I have not  consider a time out yet, the specifications of the program state that no other operation can be done if that first operation is not finished succesfully